# Создание папкок и их подпапок в Jenkins используя Ansible

Tags: ansible, jenkins

Я занимаюсь задачей по написанию Ansible плейбука для базовой инсталяции Jenkins. В рамках данный задачи требуется создавать Jenkins пайплайны в папках, либо подпапках (Folders). Соответственно, чтобы создать пайплайн внутри подпапки, требуется создать предварительно всю цепочку папок.

У меня имеется список, который выглядит вот таким образом:

```
job_lists:
  - id: 'Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/pipeline1'
    git_url: "<git url>"
  - id: 'Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/pipeline2'
    git_url: "<git url>"
  - id: 'Folder3/Folder4/pipeline3'
    git_url: "<git url>"
```

В итоге, я бы хотел получить некоторое количество строк содержащих все необходимые папки, чтобы после, добавив их в отдельный список, создать их. На выходе должен получиться вот такой список.

```
<JENKINS_HOME>/jobs/Folder1
<JENKINS_HOME>/jobs/Folder1/jobs/Folder2
<JENKINS_HOME>/jobs/Folder1/jobs/Folder2/jobs/Folder3
<JENKINS_HOME>/jobs/Folder1/jobs/Folder2/jobs/Folder3/jobs/Folder4
<JENKINS_HOME>/jobs/Folder3
<JENKINS_HOME>/jobs/Folder3/jobs/Folder4
```

Я пытался реализовать свой скрипт используя рекурсию, но Ansible явно не дает мне этого сделать, любые вложенные итерации вызова скрипта рекурсивно игнорируются. Другим способом, к сожалению, у меня это сделать не выходит. Не хватает практики.

Было бы не плохо увидеть ваше мнение о том, как это можно реализовать.

Спасибо заранее!

Comment: Так. Правильно ли я понял? Ты хочешь не создавать папки ансиблом - ты хочешь ансиблом создать список содержащий адреса, который будет скормлен Дженкинсу и который (дженкинс) сам потом их создаст? Или ты всё-таки хочешь сделать `file: path={{ from_list }} state=directory`?

Comment: Я хочу получить список всех папок в которых я после создам config.xml для каждой папки в отдельности, чтобы в итоге получить готовую структуру папок и пайплайнов внутри них. Задача - это автоматизировать процесс создания структуры папок Jenkins.